# Flask on Heroku: failed to find attribute <app_name> in run script: error H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

This is my first (proper) flask app and is essentially an extension of the Corey Schafer Flask YouTube tutorials.

Root folder:

[image: root folder contents]

`Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT run:bsstg
```

`run.py`:

```
from bsstg import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

bsstg folder:

[image: [![bsstg folder contents][2]][2] [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXnw3.png]

Full error listing:

```
2021-08-21T14:57:45.224522+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-08-21T14:57:47.689647+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
2021-08-21T14:57:47.689676+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
2021-08-21T14:57:47.691540+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py:872: FSADeprecationWarning: SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS adds significant overhead and will be disabled by default in the future.  Set it to True or False to suppress this warning.
2021-08-21T14:57:47.691542+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(FSADeprecationWarning(
2021-08-21T14:57:48.011870+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'bsstg' in 'run'.
2021-08-21T14:57:48.012140+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-21 14:57:48 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-08-21T14:57:48.012928+00:00 app[web.1]: Failed to find attribute 'bsstg' in 'run'.
2021-08-21T14:57:48.013176+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-21 14:57:48 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-08-21T14:57:48.130969+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-21 14:57:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-08-21T14:57:48.131000+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-08-21 14:57:48 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
2021-08-21T14:57:48.194499+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 4
2021-08-21T14:57:48.281397+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-08-21T14:57:55.591575+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bsstg.herokuapp.com request_id=3418126a-a6f6-4e31-93c9-0c688104f8e3 fwd="109.153.222.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-08-21T14:57:56.000370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bsstg.herokuapp.com request_id=c9360a07-edaa-4857-b5d6-4dcd445adbf7 fwd="109.153.222.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The error

> Failed to find attribute 'bsstg' in 'run'"

(bsstg is the name of my app and folder where it exists) is what I have used as the title of the question but maybe this has been leading me around in circles. Two days on this now so any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I know there are similar questions already; I think I have tried all the answers offered but I always end up with a H10 error" i.e. research effort ....? Source code, directory structure, error trace and reference to original code app was developed from .... i.e. clear question. Need is to get web page published and developed for bsstg bishops stortford sustainability transition group... i,e, useful. Please undo your downgrading of this question - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Procfile` is almost certainly wrong:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT run:bsstg
```

This runs [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) as a `web` process (one that accepts incoming HTTP and HTTPS requests). Gunicorn [expects a WSGI app as an argument](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html). You are passing in `run:bsstg`, which tells Gunicorn to run whatever `bsstg` is in the `run` module.

That leads to the error you are seeing:

```
Failed to find attribute 'bsstg' in 'run'
```

There is no `bsstg` in `run.py`; the the WSGI app is called *`app`*. Try changing it to

```
web: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT run:app
```

Then commit and redeploy.